# Does "allow background data usage" only apply for mobile data?

Tags: mobile-data, android-11

I have the samsung a32 5g.

Will an app still use wifi in the background if this is turned off?

Comment: By "turned off", do you mean the option is turned off, thus allowing data, or the option is turned on, thus blocking data usage?

Comment: Turned off, meaning it won't allow data usage. I want to know if Wi-fi is in this category of "data usage" and whether or not the app will use Wi-fi in the background regardless if this option is turned on or not.